# How to get the delimiter from a StringTokenizer?

Tags: java, string, tokenize, stringtokenizer

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, " ,.:;?![]'");
```

Is there a way to also retrieve the delimiter, in this case all thee punctuation marks?

For example, "This is a test, and is that a test too?"

I want the result of tokenization also includes the two tokens , and ?

Is that possible?

Comment: User the 3 param constructor
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-) has an overloaded constructor that takes a third `boolean` argument. Setting it to `true` will make the tokenzier return the delimiters too:

```
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s, " ,.:;?![]'", true);
// Here ---------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: That's cool! I tested use "\\s" to represent a space, why doesn't it work?

Comment: @user697911 `StringTokenzer` takes a string of characters to use as delimiters, not a regular expression.  Using `"\\s"` as the delimiter argument will result in `'\'` and `'s'` being used as delimiters, not white space.